# How to pass data between templates in Meteor with ReactiveVar

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Let's say I have a `templateA.html` with input fields and then another separate `templateB.html` which is supposed to display the values of the input fields from `templateA.html` as they are typed in. I've gotten it to work with `Session.set and Session.get` but the problem is the input values stay the same when the page is refreshed and it doesn't seem the best way to do this. I then tried to use `ReactiveVar` but since I can't find any good examples on how to use it I'm a bit lost. The following is how it works with `Session` so maybe this will help understand what I'm trying to do with `ReactiveVar`.

```
Template.templateA.events({
 'change #batch_form': function(){
    var batch_num = document.getElementById('batch_number').value;
    var dist_name = document.getElementById('distributor_name').value;

   var data = {
    batch_number: batch_num,
    dist_name: dist_name
   }

   Session.set('form_data', data);

  }

})


Template.templateB.helpers({        
    input_data(){ 
        return Session.get('form_data');
    },      
});
```

TemplateB.html

```
<template name='templateB'>
   <p>Batch #:{{input_data.batch_number}}</p>
   <p>Batch #:{{input_data.dist_name}}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: are you including `templateB` inside `templateA` or they are sibling templates?

Comment: No, it's two separate html template files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid `Session` where you can. Better scope your Template-exceeding variables with a shared scope. ES6 import/export are suitable for that.

Consider you want to share a `ReactiveDict` (which behaves like `Session`) as state between only those two Templates. You can create a new js file with the following content:

**shared.js**

```
import { ReactiveDict } from 'meteor/reactive-dict'
export const SharedAB = new ReactiveDict()
```

This gives you the control to share the state only between those Templates, that import the object.

**templateA.js**

```
import { SharedAB } from './shared.js'

Template.templateA.events({
 'change #batch_form': function(){
    var batch_num = document.getElementById('batch_number').value;
    var dist_name = document.getElementById('distributor_name').value;

   var data = {
    batch_number: batch_num,
    dist_name: dist_name
   }

   SharedAB.set('form_data', data);

  }
})
```

**templateB.js**

```
import { SharedAB } from './shared.js'

Template.templateB.helpers({        
    input_data(){ 
        return SharedAB.get('form_data');
    },      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if they don't have any parent-child relationship you can use common ReactiveDict variable(here `Session`) to pass the data between just like you're doing.

> but the problem is the input values stay the same when the page is
>   refreshed and it doesn't seem the best way to do this

for this on `onDestroyed` callback of template you can clear the `Session` variable values

```
Template.templateA.onDestroyed(function(){
   Session.set('form_data', false); // or {}
})
```

so when you come back to this page/template, there is no data to display.